# argument mismatch error in c++ code

Tags: c++

I have three file first one is bmptktevent.h second one is bmptktevent.c and third one is sbsngenerator.pC file . I have to add one attribute IPAddr. And I have added the IPAddr in these three file but when i am compiling this it is giving the error

> SbsnEvtGenerator.C", line 2107: Error: Could not find a match for BMPTktClearanceEvt::BMPTktClearanceEvt(const cpInstanceId, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, cpAttrClone, const cpAttribute, const cpAttribute, const cpAttribute, const cpAttribute, cpAttribute, cpAttribute, cpAttribute, cpAttribute, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute)

I am attaching the three file. kindly help me to come out this problem.
I have made changes in these three file. first one is

```
SbsnEvtGenerator.pC 
cpAttribute *IPAddr = _grabAttr( extraAttrs, BMPMO_IPAddress);

case IPAddressChangeEvt :
        {
            supTDO << setdl( TKT_TR_INFO ) << "Trying to "
            << "create a IPAddressChangeEvt object..."
            << endsup;

            FailIfAttrIsNull( IPAddr, BMPMO_IPAddress );

            tktEvt = new BMPTktIPAddressChangeEvt(
                    // S.Liou 01/13/98 : bmp980015.04
                    //  trblTktId, acMCN, acTktSrc,
                    trblTktId, acMCN,
                    acCGWSbsnValue, acserviceCode, 
                    actier1, actier2, actos, acbesban,
                    accustIdType, accustIdValue,acIPCustId,acDomainName, //EM_LOCAL_2
                    acserviceIdType,accustTicketNumber,acbridgeSysTktId,
                     acTktSrc,    //bmp021267.08
                    // End of bmp980015.04 [S.Liou]
                    *atLoginId, *atWkCtrId,
                    //Sameer...bmp983284.11
                                            attrAutoIndicator,
                    *IPAddr );
```

in bmptkt event.h

```
class BMPTktIPAddressChangeEvt: public BMPTktEvent
{
public:
BMPTktIPAddressChangeEvt()
  {type=IPAddressChangeEvt;}
BMPTktIPAddressChangeEvt(const cpInstanceId& tktId,
    const cpAttribute& MCN,
    const cpAttribute& cgwSbsn, //bmp980015
    const cpAttribute& serviceCode, // bmp011771
    const cpAttribute& tier1, // bmp011771.05
    const cpAttribute& tier2, // bmp011771.05
    const cpAttribute& typeOfService,   //ASV R23.0  //bmp020785.06
    const cpAttribute& BESBAN, // R24.0 EM Local #bmp021233.23
    const cpAttribute& CustIdType,  //EM_LOCAL_2
    const cpAttribute& CustIdValue, //EM_LOCAL_2
    const cpAttribute& IPCustId,
            const cpAttribute& DomainName,
    const cpAttribute& serviceIdType, //IP Cable #bmp021267    R24.0
    const cpAttribute &custTicketNumber,
    const cpAttribute &bridgeSysTktId,
    const cpAttribute& srcSys, const cpAttribute& loginId,
    const cpAttribute& workCenter,
    const cpAttribute& autoInd,  //Sameer...bmp983284.14
    const cpAttribute& IPAddr ) ;
};
```

and in bmptktevent.C

Comment: Is that really a constructor with 32 parameters?  Wow.

Comment: Wow. This signature alone should be sent to TDWTF.

Comment: No. Just no. Reject this reality and substitute your own by refactoring the code, with the constructor taking some sort of aggregate that combines logical groupings of those various parameters. This sort of code is just unmaintainable as you've discovered.

Comment: Maybe you're putting in too many arguments. You could try putting less in. Or different ones. Or you might need to put in more arguments. (Even more? Good grief!) Post the code where BMPTktClearanceEvt is declared for better answers. Not all 2107+ lines though please.

Comment: i think you are missing one of the cpAttrClone parameters

Comment: Why not use `std::map<X, cpAttribute>` (where `X` is an enumeration `{ MCN, ..., IPAddr }`) for the constructor argument? Boost::assign can "concatenate" `maps` and C++11 has `initializer_list`.

Answer (score 3):

> Error: Could not find a match for BMPTktClearanceEvt::BMPTktClearanceEvt( [...] cpAttribute, **cpAttribute*, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute*, cpAttribute***, cpAttribute)

Notice how the sixth to second last are pointers. You're not dereferencing enough:

```
// these are the last 6 parameters you're passing:
acbridgeSysTktId,
acTktSrc,    //bmp021267.08
// End of bmp980015.04 [S.Liou]
*atLoginId, *atWkCtrId,
//Sameer...bmp983284.11
attrAutoIndicator,
*IPAddr
```

See if any of those are double pointers. Also, the first few parameters you're actually passing are `cpAttrClone`. Are those implicitly convertible to `cpAttribute`? If not, that's also a source of error.

Comment: That said, *please* burn that code and refactor it to something nicer.